Measurement lines suddenly disappear
I use the Measure option to draw measurement lines in the project. The lines draw, I can angle them, I can edit and delete them. Great!
The problem however is that after I add a bunch of measurements (say 20-30 as needed by my project), at some point after I have drawn them, they simply disappear! I can't tell when, they just go poof when I am not zoomed out and looking at them but rather working on zoomed in details in my project.
Even if I save my project while I can see lines, the measurement lines WILL save, and then when I re-open the project there they are... but then at some point while I'm working (and I do not know what is triggering this) in a place where there are no measurements -- I zoom out to refer to one of those measurements but poof!! -- all my measurement lines are gone!!
What could be causing their disappearance??  is there some sort of time limit for their display? or some limit as to how many can be drawn??
(for context, in Viewport Overlays I have Annotations ON, in Mesh Edit Overlays I have Freestyle Edge and Face Marks both ON)
Why are my measurement lines drawn suddenly disappearing?
Thanks.
(Blender 4.2.2LTS, Win11.)

Hello, are you talking about the Measure option in the Mesh Edit Mode Overlays?

In Edit or Object mode, using MEASURE in the T Menu to draw measurement lines.   That working.
"the problem" is in the 2nd paragraph.
The following is just fyi, in case anyone is wondering what options I have turned on, since I've seen some other posts requiring that these be turned on, so I'm simply informing folks reading this that I HAVE the following checked ON:
a) In the Viewport Overlays dropdown, I have Annotations checked ON
b) In the Mesh Edit Overlays dropdown, I have both Freestyle Edge and Face Marks both checked ON.
Even with these checked on, I still get "the problem".
